# Nuxt fetch method, if API error make whole site respond with 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

How do I make a nuxt site respond with 404 when a 404 error is raised on the API.

The call is made on the client-side so `fetch` method used:

Here is a demo: [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-moore-r757h?file=/pages/index.vue)

### code snippets

**index.vue**

```
<template>
  <section>
    <h1>Testing custom error</h1>
    <p v-if="$fetchState.pending">Fetching mountains...</p>
    <PageError v-else-if="$fetchState.error" />
    <p v-else>Fetch success</p>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import PageError from '~/components/PageError.vue'
export default {
  components : {
    PageError
  },
  async fetch() {
    await this.$axios.$get("https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountain");
  },
  fetchOnServer: false,
};
</script>
```

**PageError.vue**

```
<!--Make this component respond with 404 -->
<template>
  <section>
    <h1>404 item not found</h1>
    <p>How to I make site respond with 404</p>
  </section>
</template>
```

**Why is this a problem**

- crawlers don't notice the page has no content and end up indexing the 404 pages...where as I want google not to crawl sites with 404...until issues a fixed and I can validate fix from `search console`.

Instead of responding with just mere text that an error has occurred and page was not found....I would like the status of the `site` to be 404.

**NB:** I could add a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"/>` when error component is triggered...just asking if its possible with NUXT to get 404.

Answer (score 0):

I gotta look into details itself, but so far I think you need to catch an error with axios, a bit like:

```
...      
.then(response => {
        return response
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return error
        // return Promise.reject(error)
      })
...
```

And then you can v-if="...error" or so to, to make the component appear.

I hope that pushes you in a better direction.

Comment: That's exactly what am doing...asking for a better way.